# Duplicate entry error by using Gson with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2, gson

I am using retrofit , `rxjava` and `gson` for `api` call. I am not getting any error while building or cleaning the app but as soon as I am running the app in device; I am  getting error i.e.

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class**

depedencies file app build.gradle is:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:dp-1'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.8'


}
```

**Note : I have been tried many solution given in stackoverflow like excluding gson from retrofit and all.**
Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try excluding 'gson' dependencies from retrofit?

Comment: yes i tried that one already

Comment: try removing Multidex and rebuild project

Comment: and check your lib folder if there is any gson jar file. if it exists then delete it

Comment: What you are  hiding from us is "libs", which may have gson jar, that is conflicting with "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0"

Comment: @RajuSharma i am using 2 libs one for scanning and other is PacketProcessor which doesn't include gson

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
```

Try to use dependencies as shown above

Comment: Try to Invalidate Cache& Restart. If not working, show your full build.gradle. Also, remove any packagingOptions, it works for me without them

Answer (score -1):

Use below code in `build.gradle`(in app level after `buildType` code) file and rebuild again project;

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' // will not include LICENSE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

Comment: where i have to include this?app level or project level?

Comment: It is already mentioned i.e. in `build.gradle` file(app level)